# How do you go back to previous version of your project or create back up save in pycharm?

Tags: python, html, css, pycharm

I want to make some major changes to my code, but these changes could break the whole thing so I want a save or something I could revert to in pycharm. Is there some way making something like that, especially for a huge project with many files.

Comment: Use version control. I hear all the cool kids use git.

Comment: git, mercurial, SVN

Comment: Also all of the JetBrains IDEs have a "local history"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using git? It's used for something called source control, which allows you to manage multiple versions of your files. You can even create branches which allow you to try out a change in one version and if you end up liking it, you can merge it with your other versions. https://git-scm.com/ Github is a great way to store your versions in the cloud in case your computer gets destroyed. https://github.com/

Comment: Thanks for the help!